# Ignore exceptions when changing column formula in Excel table

Tags: optimization, performance, vba, excel

The new table feature on Excel is excellent and you can specify a column formula as well as exceptions on the column. However, if you want to change the column formula, Excel will rewrite the whole column including the exceptions. I've tried to avoid this issue with the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'Prevent from firing if changed cell is outside a table
    If Target.ListObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Prevent from firing if cell is changed to a value
    If Val(Target.Formula) = Target.Value Then Exit Sub
    'Prevent from firing if multiple cells where changed
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    'Disable events
    ToggleWaitMode

    'Prevent change if user already stated calculation as manual
    Dim bCheckCalculationMode As Boolean
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        bCheckCalculationMode = True
    End If

    'Declarations
    Dim sTableName As String
    Dim lNbLines As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sFieldName As String
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim sOldFormula As String
    Dim sNewFormula As String
    Dim aExceptionFormulas() As String
    Dim aExceptionAddresses() As String

    sTableName = Target.ListObject.Name
    lNbLines = Range(sTableName).Rows.Count
    sFieldName = "[" & Intersect(Target.ListObject.HeaderRowRange, Target.EntireColumn).Value & "]"

    'Add a new row to get the column formula
    Range(sTableName).ListObject.ListRows.Add
    sOldFormula = Range(sTableName & sFieldName)(lNbLines).Formula

    sNewFormula = Target.Formula

    'Loop on each cell of the column to get each exception formulas and addresses in arrays
    i = 1
    For Each cel In Range(sTableName & sFieldName)
        If cel.Formula <> sOldFormula Then
            ReDim Preserve aExceptionFormulas(1 To i)
            ReDim Preserve aExceptionAddresses(1 To i)
            aExceptionFormulas(i) = cel.Formula
            aExceptionAddresses(i) = cel.Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cel

    'Delete added row and replace column to new formula
    Range(sTableName).ListObject.ListRows(lNbLines).Delete
    Range(sTableName & sFieldName).Formula = sNewFormula

    If i > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(aExceptionFormulas)
            Range(aExceptionAddresses(i)).Formula = aExceptionFormulas(i)
        Next i
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

CleanExit:
    If bCheckCalculationMode Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ToggleWaitMode False
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleWaitMode(Optional ByVal bWait As Boolean = True)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not bWait
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = Not bWait
End Sub
```

The code works but it's really ugly. Do you think it's possible to optimize it? For example by finding the Inconsistent Formulas?

Edit: I've modified the code accordingly to the great advices of Mat's Mug. I hope it got better. Can the added row be avoided? It's just a workaround to get the column formula.

Comment: 1. what is "ugly" about the code? 2. use meaningful names for your variables

Comment: I modified the code slightly and tried to get better variables. Also the ugly part is when I added an empty row just to get the column formula.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
> ```

The `Worksheet.Change` event gets fired whenever *anything* changes *anywhere* in the worksheet. Code you write in a handler for that event *must* do its business as fast as possible, or it can significantly affect (negatively) the performance of the whole Excel instance.

Whenever possible, avoid using this event for *anything* that doesn't need to run *whenever anything changes anywhere in the worksheet*.

---

> ```
> Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
> If Target.Count = 1 Then
> Application.EnableEvents = False
> ```

Your indentation is off, the assignment `Application.EnableEvents = False` should be one <kbd>Tab</kbd> further to the right.

I like that you're disabling automatic calculation and other worksheet event handlers, but I don't understand why only one of them is under the `If` block.

> ```
>     Application.EnableEvents = True
>     End If
>     ActiveSheet.Calculate
> End Sub
> ```

The result of this is that you're calculating the active sheet, but you've disabled automatic calculation of the workbook *without reinstating it*, and you end up *systematically* calling `ActiveSheet.Calculate`, which gives the illusion that automatic calculation is still enabled.

> ```
> tb = Target.ListObject.Name
> ```

If the modified cell is outside of a `ListObject`, this is where your code blows up, and because you're not handling run-time errors, this is where your user sees a VBA debugger prompt and might accidentally end up in your source code with a puzzled facial expression.

Whenever you start writing a method/procedure/function in VBA, you should start with something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'code goes here

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume CleanExit
    Resume 'unreachable code, for debugging
End Sub
```

Now you can put a breakpoint on the `Resume CleanExit` instruction, and can inspect the `Err` object and then set the `Resume` dead code as the next statement to be executed, and be taken (<kbd>F8</kbd>) exactly on the line the error came from, whenever anything goes wrong with this code.

---

> ```
> Dim tb As String
> tb = Target.ListObject.Name
> ```

If `tb` is supposed to be the name of a table, then why is it not called `tableName`? **Use descriptive identifiers when naming things!**

> ```
> Dim l As Long
> Dim i As Long
> Dim s As String
> Dim cel As Range
> Dim fmla As String
> Dim nfmla As String
> Dim mfmla() As String
> Dim mad() As String
> ```

Oh, boy. Need I say more?

---

I'm not going to review your algorithm (not going to try to wrap my head around those cryptic identifiers), but one thing I can say is that, for the reasons explained at the top of this answer, I'd start the procedure like this:

```
If Target.ListObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

That way you don't bother with anything if the active cell isn't in a table, and the handler can't blow up either when you later try to get the table's name.

Also by only testing for `Target.Count = 1` all you're really doing, is ensuring that the current selection only has a single cell. This means if a user selects an entire row (or column) and starts entering data, your code happily sets calculation mode to manual, skipts the entire handler and recalculates the sheet.

Hence, the next thing I'd do after ensuring the `Target` range has a `ListObject`, would be to toggle calculation mode and event firing. It's probably best to write a small procedure just for that:

```
Private Sub ToggleWaitMode(Optional ByVal wait As Boolean = True)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(wait, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not wait
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = Not wait
End Sub
```

That leaves your handler with pretty much only the code that's relevant for its task:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If Target.ListObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ToggleWaitMode

    '...

CleanExit:
    ToggleWaitMode False
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume CleanExit
    Resume 'unreachable code, for debugging
End Sub
```

---

I don't like the `ReDim Preserve` array handling. You know how many cells you're going to be iterating over (`Range(tb & s).Count`), therefore you know the size of the array you're going to need *at the moment you're declaring it*. You'll probably gain some performance by doing this, depending on how many cells the range has.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time. I took your comment into account and changed my code slightly and added some commentaries. I will change the code above according to your advise. However I disagree on the use of ReDim Preserve as I can't tell how many exceptions there will be in the considered column.

Comment: ++, great! @Mat's Mug